# How to extract the opens of mobile push in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, push-notification, tracking

I am trying to extract the opens of mobile push from marketing cloud using API. I was able to send the push notifications and get the delivery status of the push as well. The opens of these notifications are registered in account but the problem is that I am not able to extract these opens using API. Is there any way to get these opens out.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, the Marketing Cloud has no supported way to pull push analytics from an API.

The general way to do it is run the detail extract report to get your sends and opens.